# Couchbase : Batch Read Latency

Tags: scala, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

While Couchbase scales well for single key reads, I am observing higher latency when reading batch of 100 keys at a time. Is there a right way to use couchbase-client for batch reads? Currently, the code I have in Scala is:

```
Observable.from(keys).flatMap(key => {
        rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions.toScalaObservable(
      cacheStorageBucket.async().get(StringDocument.create(key))).filter(_ != null)
      .map(d => key -> d.content().getObj[T])
      })
.toList.toBlocking.single.toMap
```

Couchbase client version :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version are you in? 2.1.6 is almost 5 years old, you should ideally use at least 2.7.16

Comment: I am working with couchbase-server-community version 4.5.1